# jQuery if data attr is greater than x, add class, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

On my [page](https://lbrynomics.com) I am running the below code to add a class to table rows past row 400, but it's not working. I don't seem to be able to work out why, so have just put it down to a conflict since the recent WordPress jQuery shake up, or is there an error in the code? If the code is correct and it's just a wordpress error, then maybe I should convert in to pure JS?

```
jQuery(function($){  
  $('[rank]').each(function(){
     if ( $(this).data('rank') > 400) {
         $(this).addClass('all-channels');
     } 
     else { 
         $(this).addClass('top-500');
   }});
 });
```

[image]

- There are no errors in the Consol.
- I've tried with `.attr('rank')` instead of `.data('rank')`, but still no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Tried using parseInt to the data?

Comment: `$(this).data('rank')` won't work with `<td rank=123>` as it's not a `data-` attribute - change your html to `<tr data-rank=` and it will work as `.data()` coerces the correct data type (will be an int) while `.attr()` is always a string

Comment: Ahh, that had crossed my mind. I'll try that now.

Comment: Nope. Still not working. Scratches head! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the rank value, just use the [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function like `.attr('rank')`. Then don't forget to convert this value to a number using `parsInt()`:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('[rank]').each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).attr('rank')) > 400) {
      $(this).addClass('all-channels');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('top-500');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.all-channels {
  color: red;
}

.top-500 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p rank="2">
  test
</p>
<p rank="401">
  test
</p>
```

Comment: No luck. I even tried adding the same jQuery lib, but that just ended up breaking the whole site, which makes me lean even more towards this being a WP conflict since their jQuery shake up. https://imgur.com/LbisPFI

Comment: So it doesn't seems to be the problem here because the example I give works as expected.

Comment: Yeah. I've tried just about everything, that should work, but no luck. I'll probably just have to rewrite it in pure JS. I think it's a WP jQuery issue. I've had so many issues since the WP 5.5 update.

Comment: @InvariantChange Could you get the current version of it?

Comment: When I added `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the script, it broke the whole site. It conflicted with the current version. See above Imgur image,

Comment: Ah ha! I found the issue. It works if I add say,  `data-rank="455"` manually, but not on the dynamically produced table. I probably just have to defer it so it runs after the table is created.

Comment: @InvariantChange Probably you should open a new question for that :) But please `validate` this one since it answer the question :)

Comment: Yeah! Found the issue now. So all good. I'll mark you as the answer, even though a new one got in the way :)